# Halo 3 skulls missing

Tags: halo-3

So I had all the skulls and now one is missing the one where if you shoot grunts they turn into confetti and I re did the lvl and it is not there at all unless it's in the ground or something I can't find it any answerers?

Comment: Do you mean that in the menu where you select your skulls you can no longer select that skull? (IIRC it is Grunt Birthday Party, yes?)  Or that you don't see it in the level?  Or is it both?

Comment: Both of them in lvl and in the menu

Answer (score 1):

The "Grunt Birthday Party" skull can be found in the "Crow's Nest" level, in the access tunnels with the Buggers flying around, just after a Cortana vision.

To find the skull, you need to (carefully) drop down to the level below, by moving backwards immediately after you fall off the ledge above. This can be easily missed, so take care.

Note: This is a "Silver" Skull, so when you pick it up, you will not get any notification that the skull has been collected, other than it appearing in the menu.

Comment: I can't find it there of any where on lvl and out

Comment: @Inofearu try reloading the level

Comment: I tried that but still missing?